# Java draw line and pressKey to change color

Tags: java, awt, paint

I am trying to draw a line, and change color every time I press 'c' for example. I have 5 boolean variables

```
boolean redColor = false;   
boolean blueColor = false; 
boolean greenColor = false;
boolean yellowColor = false;
boolean defaultColor = false;
```

I have a variable `int counter = 0` and I use it to increment in function `keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`. Because I have 5 variables, when counter reach value 6, I reset counter and it starts again from 1, with red color. In `paint()` method I check those boolean values above, and if they are true, I change color.

First time , until counter is reseting, I can change colors fine, but after counter reset, my colors will not change. I will write here exactly what it happens:

```
counter = 1 => color red   
counter = 2 => color blue    
counter = 3 => color green   
counter = 4 => color yellow    
counter = 5 => color black(default)
counter = 6 => reset color back to 1
```

until here everything works fine, but when counter resets and increments again, color is still the same, black, for any value of counter.
I will write here a part of my code, maybe is not the best way to do it, but I'm new in AWT. I wish to use awt for this. Thank you for reading my post.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if(mousePressed == true)
        {
            g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);    
             if(redColor == true)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);    
            }
            if(blueColor == true)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
            if(greenColor == true)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
            if(yellowColor == true)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
            if(defaultColor == true)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
        }
    }



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'c')
        {
            counter ++;
            if(counter == 1)
                redColor = true;
            if(counter == 2)
                blueColor = true;
            if(counter == 3)
                greenColor = true;
            if(counter == 4)
                yellowColor = true;
            if(counter == 5)
            {
                defaultColor= true;
            }
            else if(counter == 6)
                counter = 1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting all colors true and none false, so you end up drawing the same line over and over, and eventually, the only color you see is black. A solution is to set all booleans to false within your key pressed method, and then only set the correct one to true.

Myself I'd do things differently by using an array or ArrayList of Color, and then incrementing the counter and selecting the correct item out of the array. e.g.,

```
private Color[] colors = { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK };
private int index = 0;
private Color color = Color.BLACK;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    // if correct key pressed:
    if(e.getKeyChar() == 'c') {
        color = colors[index]; // select appropriate color
        repaint();

        index++;
        index %= colors.length;  // set index to 0 if == length of array
     }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);   // *** don't forget me! ***
    g.setColor(color);
    // draw line with Color
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Note how much simpler this code is.

Note, if this is Swing, you wouldn't use KeyListeners but rather KeyBindings, and you'd override paintComponent, not paint.

Also don't forget to call the super's paint method!

Comment: Yes , I seen your first comment and I made it ! now it works, Thank you very much and Merry Christmas ! :)

Comment: @ClaudiuM: you're welcome. Please not edits to the answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Set the other colors false, otherwise in the end all of them will be true, and that's why it is black after the first run.

```
        if(counter == 1)
            redColor = true;
            blueColor = false;
            greenColor = false;
            yellowColor = false;
            blackColor = false;
        if(counter == 2)
            redColor = false;
            blueColor = true;
            greenColor = false;
            yellowColor = false;
            blackColor = false;
        if(counter == 3)
            //.....and so on
```

Comment: I've seen @Hovercraft Full Of Eels comment and I made it exactly like this :). Thank you for your reply  ! It works, Merry Christmas !

Comment: A lot simpler would be to set all xxxxColor variables to false at the beginning of the block and the setting true only the correct one. That will shorten this code considerably, but 1+ for identifying the error.

Comment: Thank you, and yes I can see your code is much nicer.